# How to retrieve particular data from django models?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

I am trying to fetch the record from django model where email=some POST-data and pass=post data.

Here's my models.py

```
class candidate(models.Model):
    fname=models.CharField("First name ",max_length=20,default="")
    lname=models.CharField("Last name ",max_length=20,default="")
    email=models.EmailField("Email ",max_length=254,primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField("Password ",max_length=100,default="")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname+" " +self.lname
```

and in views.py

```
def login(request):
    print("hello login")
    if request.method=='POST':
        user=request.POST['radioBtn']
        print(user)
        try:
            user=request.POST['radioBtn']
            print(user)
            if(user=="Candidate"):
                print("candidate login")
                udetails=candidate.objects.get(email=request.POST['emails'],password=request.POST['passwd'])
               
        except:
            messages.error(request,'login failed...')
            return render(request,'login.html')
    return render(request,'login.html')
```

Here I used

```
get(email=request.POST['emails'],password=request.POST['passwd'])
```

to fetch the records but it's not working. I have used the same way to fetch records my other project and it was working there.

Is there any way to get the particular record by comparing the data we got from post request and display that record only? as we were doing in mysql like

```
select * 
from table 
where email = someemail and pass = somepasswd
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no typos in your views.py:

```
udetails=candidate.objects.get(email=request.POST['emails'],password=request.POST['passwd'])
```

Are the field names in your html/models.py also `emails` and `passwd`, and not `email` and `password`?

You can check the incoming request like this:

```
def login(request):
   print(request.POST)
   # ...
```

Comment: No, there's no typos, its perfectly performing POST request,here's what I got after print(request.POST)--- <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['cMxmUtPrtwLH2FNAAcwI01ge65BQ4TB799B3jBnkofVxOly5aceacrrMDl7LU5IN'], 'emails': ['ajay24@gmail.com'], 'passwd': ['1234'], 'radioBtn': ['Candidate']}>, still can't login...

Comment: Is there any other ways to do it ? any suggestions pls?